# EF handling two tables with one DBContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have two `SQL Server` tables which are exactly same, `Table1` and `Table2`. `Table1` has 3 datas and `Table2` has 1 data. I have a `DBContext` class such that,

```
public class DbModelContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly string _tableName;

        public DbModelContext(string tableName)
            : base("name=TestXEntities")
        {
            _tableName = tableName;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<DbModel>().ToTable(_tableName);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }

        public virtual DbSet<DbModel> Tests { get; set; }
    }
```

I try to find the total data size `c` with this code,

```
    var context1 = new DbModelContext("Test1");
    var a = context1.Tests.Count();

    var context2 = new DbModelContext("Test2");
    var b = context2.Tests.Count();

    var c = a + b;
```

When I run this I get `c = 6` (both `a` and `b` equal to count of `Table1`). If I replace the strings `Test1` and `Test2` in above code than I get `c = 2` (both `a` and `b` equal to count of `Table2`). However, in both cases I expect to get `c = 4`. It always seems to take the name of the first table into consideration.

What's wrong this code ? What should I do to get `c = 4` ?

Thanks for reading and for your help.

Comment: Add creating table code

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_1 _Typically, this method is called only once when the first instance of a derived context is created_

Comment: Thanks, I did read this before but now it make sense.